# How to close physical connection

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Calling Dispose on the NpgSqlConnection returns the connection to the pool.
How to close the physical connection?

Answer (score 2):

You do not. There is no proper way generally to manipulate pooled connections. In pretty much all pools I have ever seen they time out after some minutes.

If you read the manual, you can see that you actually have full control over pool behavior via the connection string.

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

is the relevant documentation, found after 2 seconds looking. There is a whole section for pool parameters, one i.e. turning the pooling behavior totally off.

If you do not want a connection to be used and go into the pool, use a connection string that disables the pool for this particular connection.

Comment: in my current scenario disabling pool will work, but still looking for better solution.